# chrome extension content.js crashes dynamic websites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, dynamic, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to insert an overlay through a custom chrome extension, however, when simply adding HTML to the body of the document the dynamic websites will crash and buttons will not work + connections will not work.

Is there any other ways to approach this without crashing the applications?

**content.js**

```
document.body.innerHTML += `<div>innerHTML</div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to construct the element then appending it to the document body.

Here's an example where I have an HTML file that I am fetching with the content script and adding it to the page.

manifest.json:

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "content/views/overlay.html"
]
```

content.js:

```js
const htmlBackdropLink = chrome.extension.getURL('content/views/overlay.html');
// Get overlay HTML
const overlayRes = await fetch(htmlBackdropLink);
const overlayHtml = await backdropRes.text();

// Create div and set HTML
const wrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
wrapperDiv.innerHTML = overlayHtml;

document.body.appendChild(wrapperDiv)
```

Comment: Yes, appending worked!